Cant create VM instance from artifact image via node sdk
I am trying to create a VM instance based on a artifact image which works fine in the console and creating VM instances works as well via the sdk even attaching the image works even tho this is no public api via the metadata but as soon as I define service accounts the instance will be created and deleted right away. The retuned result form that all is the same and look just as a successful one. without the service account defined it works fine but I need them to access the image.
I am not using the GKE as I dont need the managed stuff around it and feel like this way will be more cost efficient and the instance is fixed and doesnt need to scale
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { InstancesClient } from "@google-cloud/compute";

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Initialize the Google Cloud Compute client
const instancesClient = new InstancesClient({
  keyFilename: "./src/service-account.json",
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post("/create-vm", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { name, zone, machineType, sourceImage } = req.body;

    const instanceName = "dummy-service-v8";
    const result = await instancesClient.insert({
      project: "stellar-cumulus-******-n4",
      zone: "us-central1-a",
      instanceResource: {
        name: instanceName,
        machineType: "zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/e2-micro",
        tags: {
          items: ["p3000"],
        },
        disks: [
          {
            boot: true,
            autoDelete: true,
            initializeParams: {
              diskName: instanceName + "-disk",
              diskSizeGb: 10,
              diskType:
                "projects/stellar-cumulus-******-n4/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-balanced",
              labels: {},
              sourceImage:
                "projects/cos-cloud/global/images/cos-stable-117-18613-0-79",
            },
          },
        ],
        labels: {
          "goog-ec-src": "vm_add-rest",
          "container-vm": "cos-stable-117-18613-0-79",
        },
        serviceAccounts: [
          {
            email: "*********-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
            scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
          },
        ],
        metadata: {
          items: [
            {
              key: "gce-container-declaration",
              value: `spec:\n  containers:\n  - name: ${instanceName}\n    image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/stellar-cumulus-******-n4/dummy-service/dummy-service:v8\n    stdin: false\n    tty: false\n  restartPolicy: Always\n# This container declaration format is not public API and may change without notice. Please\n# use gcloud command-line tool or Google Cloud Console to run Containers on Google Compute Engine.`,
            },
          ],
        },
        networkInterfaces: [
          {
            accessConfigs: [
              {
                name: "External NAT",
                networkTier: "PREMIUM",
              },
            ],
            stackType: "IPV4_ONLY",
            subnetwork:
              "projects/stellar-cumulus-******-n4/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default",
          },
        ],
      },
    });

    res.json({ message: "VM created successfully", result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating VM:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to create VM" });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});



As you mentioned, without a Service Account it works fine. So issue may be with Service Account permissions, By default Compute engine has Access Scopes. This feature will limit the permissions assigned to the service account. VM Access Scopes do not grant permissions.
Go to the Google Cloud Console, go to the VM instances select Allow full access to all Cloud APIs. which means that the service account is no longer restricted and permissions are now managed by IAM roles assigned to the service account.

If the service account has no IAM roles, then no API methods can be run by the service account on that instance. So add the required IAM role to the service account for that you can upload to Artifact Registry. Go to IAM and set permissions on Artifact Registry to write (roles/artifactregistry.writer) Granting access to Compute Engine instances.

Thanks for the comment. I solved it by just moving to python so its not a permissions issue but its still weird why its not working in node

Your Node.JS code mostly works for me.
BILLING="..."
PROJECT="..."
REGION="..."

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

package.json:
{
  "name": "79093452",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/compute": "^4.9.0",
    "express": "^4.21.2"
  }
}

index.js:
const express = require("express");

const { InstancesClient } = require("@google-cloud/compute");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//const KEY = process.env.KEY;
const PROJECT = process.env.PROJECT;
const NUMBER = process.env.NUMBER;
const REGION = process.env.REGION;
const IMAGE = process.env.IMAGE;

// Initialize the Google Cloud Compute client
const instancesClient = new InstancesClient({
//  keyFilename: KEY,
});

app.use(express.json());
app.post("/create-vm", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, zone, machineType, sourceImage } = req.body;

    const result = await instancesClient.insert({
      project: PROJECT,
      zone: zone,
      instanceResource: {
        name: name,
        machineType: `zones/${zone}/machineTypes/${machineType}`,
        tags: {
          items: ["p3000"],
        },
        disks: [
          {
            boot: true,
            autoDelete: true,
            initializeParams: {
              diskName: `${name}-disk`,
              diskSizeGb: 10,
              diskType: `projects/${PROJECT}/zones/${zone}/diskTypes/pd-balanced`,
              labels: {},
              sourceImage: `projects/cos-cloud/global/images/${sourceImage}`,
            },
          },
        ],
        labels: {
          "goog-ec-src": "vm_add-rest",
          "container-vm": sourceImage,
        },
        serviceAccounts: [
          {
            email: `${NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`,
            scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
          },
        ],
        metadata: {
          items: [
            {
              key: "gce-container-declaration",
              value: `spec:\n  containers:\n  - name: ${name}\n    image: ${IMAGE}\n    stdin: false\n    tty: false\n  restartPolicy: Always`
            },
          ],
        },
        networkInterfaces: [
          {
            accessConfigs: [
              {
                name: "External NAT",
                networkTier: "PREMIUM",
              },
            ],
            stackType: "IPV4_ONLY",
            subnetwork: `projects/${PROJECT}/regions/${REGION}/subnetworks/default`,
          },
        ],
      },
    });

    res.json({ message: "VM created successfully", result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating VM:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to create VM" });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Run:
IMAGE="gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue"

PROJECT=${PROJECT} \
NUMBER=$(\
  gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(projectNumber)") \
REGION=${REGION} \
IMAGE=${IMAGE} \
node index.js

Then:
NAME="..."
ZONE="${REGION}-c"

curl \
--request POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://localhost:3000/create-vm \
-d "{
  \"name\":\"${NAME}\",
  \"zone\":\"${ZONE}\",
  \"machineType\":\"e2-micro\",
  \"sourceImage\":\"cos-stable-117-18613-0-79\"
}"

Then:
gcloud compute instances describe ${NAME} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(status)"

RUNNING

And:
COMMAND='docker container ls --format="{{.Image}}"'

gcloud compute ssh ${NAME} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--command="${COMMAND}"

gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue

